# How do I correct the dimensions on my variable?

Tags: r, dimensions

I'm attempting to eventually make a confusion matrix in order to check the accuracy of the findings.  However, I'm getting an error concerning the dimensions in a variable.

```
> predval <- predict(t1, test_data)
> head(predval)
 
> pred <- factor(ifelse(predval[,2] > 0.5, 1,0))
Error in predval[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions
> typeof(predval)
[1] "double"
> dim(predval)
NULL
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a named `vector` soo it doesn't have those dimension

```
 factor(ifelse(predicted_values > 0.5, 1,0))
```